# How do I change a dropdown menu to radio buttons?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, radio-button

I have a drop-down menu with a list of choices:

```
select_tag(:"answers[#{question.question_no}]", options_for_select( [['Agree Strongly', 7], ['Agree Mostly', 6], ['Agree Somewhat', 5], ['Neither Agree Nor Disagree', 4], ['Disagree Somewhat', 3], ['Disagree Mostly', 2], ['Disagree Strongly', 1]] ))
```

I would like it so that it displays seven radio buttons instead. How is this possible. if at all?

Comment: For the future, when you ask a question requesting code, Stack Overflow expects you to show where you've searched, what didn't work about those results, and anything you've tried on your own showing you've made an effort to answer the problem on your own. Failing to do that puts the question off-topic and subject to being closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <%- [['Agree Strongly', 7],
       ['Agree Mostly', 6],
       ['Agree Somewhat', 5],
       ['Neither Agree Nor   Disagree', 4],
       ['Disagree Somewhat', 3],
       ['Disagree Mostly', 2],
       ['Disagree Strongly', 1]].each do |button| %>
      <%= radio_button_tag :name, button.first, :value => button.last %>
    <% end %>
```

and even better to list the controller

...controller

```
  def some_action
  @choices = [['Agree Strongly', 7],
           ['Agree Mostly', 6],
           ['Agree Somewhat', 5],
           ['Neither Agree Nor   Disagree', 4],
           ['Disagree Somewhat', 3],
           ['Disagree Mostly', 2],
           ['Disagree Strongly', 1]]
  end
```

...views

```
   <% @choices.each do |button| %>
     <%= radio_button_tag :name, button.first, :value => button.last %>
   <% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get multiple radio buttons just use rails form helper: `radio_button_tag`

```
radio_button_tag(:"answers[#{question.question_no}]", '7')
label_tag(:answer_agree_strongly, "Agree Strongly")
radio_button_tag(:"answers[#{question.question_no}]", '6')
label_tag(:answer_agree_mostly, "Agree Mostly")
...
```

All radio buttons that share same name will be grouped and users will be able to select only one.

P.S. probably you want to iterate over your array of options to make code more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Sure that's possible :)

```
<% ['Agree Strongly', ..., 'Disagree Strongly'].each do |option| %>
  <%= radio_button_tag(:name, option) %>
  <%= label_tag("name_#{option}") %>
<% end %>
```